# Drawing a shape by clicking a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paint, jcomponent

I am currently trying to draw a figure by clicking a button. My problems occurs when I click the button and it does not show up in the panel, but I know it's drawing because it runs through the loop.

The drawing will occur when I request the panel to draw it inside the constructor, but not inside the button, inside the constructor

If i put the code in the method "stuff()" inside the constructor it will draw everything just fine.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        MainFrame f = new MainFrame();
    }
public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
public MainFrame(){
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Shweet Button");
    button1.setBounds(185, 10, 130, 20);
    frame.setBounds(1680/4,1050/4,500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.add(button1);
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            stuff();
        }
    });
}
public void stuff(){
    for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++){
        panel.add(new paintComponent());
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(80);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
static class paintComponent extends JComponent{
    public int options;
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);

        if(options == 0){
            options = 1;
            g2.drawOval(50, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+100, 50, 50);
            g2.drawOval(60, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+110, 8, 8);
            g2.fillOval(60, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+110, 8, 8);
            g2.drawOval(80, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+110, 8, 8);
            g2.fillOval(80, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+110, 8, 8);
            g2.drawArc(65, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+130, 100, 0, 140, 30);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+150, 75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+220);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+180, 100, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+160);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+180, 65, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+210);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+220, 50, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+260);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+220, 100, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+260);
        }else if(options == 1){
            options = 0;
            g2.drawOval(50, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+100, 50, 50);
            g2.drawOval(60, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+110, 8, 8);
            g2.fillOval(60, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+110, 8, 8);
            g2.drawOval(80, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+110, 8, 8);
            g2.fillOval(80, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+110, 8, 8);
            g2.drawArc(65, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+130, 100, 0, 140, 30);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+150, 75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+220);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+180, 100, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+180);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+180, 65, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+210);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+220, 50, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+260);
            g2.drawLine(75, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+220, 100, (JFrame.HEIGHT/2)+260);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're block the Event Dispatching Thread, which is preventing it from updating the UI

Comment: do you have to post so much code? Will it suffice if you just have one drawOvel line for each of the two options?

Comment: Applcation Looks like hang the Execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, which is responsible for, amongst other things, processing paint requests.

You should never do anything like this...

```
for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++){
    panel.add(new paintComponent());
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.repaint();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(80);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Within the EDT.  Apart from the fact you are adding multiple new components to your UI every 80 milliseconds, you are also blocking the thread that is responsible for updating your screen...

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Animation of this type should be handled by a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Custom painting should be performed in the `paintComponent` method, as a general rule.  You should also be calling `super.paintXxx` first as a matter of course.  There's a lot of working going in the background that needs to be taken care of, especially if the component is transparent.

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

Save your sanity and learn how to use layout managers, they will make your life easier in the long run.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MainFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                MainFrame f = new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private WavePane waver;

    public MainFrame() {
        waver = new WavePane();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Shweet Button");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.add(button1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stuff();
            }
        });
        panel.add(waver);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void stuff() {
//        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
//            panel.add(new paintComponent());
//            panel.setBackground(Color.black);
//            frame.repaint();
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(80);
//            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
//                e1.printStackTrace();
//            }
//        }
        waver.walk(!waver.isWaving());
    }

    public class WavePane extends JComponent {

        private int options;
        private Timer timer;

        public WavePane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            timer = new Timer(80, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("tick");
                    options++;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public void walk(boolean walk) {
            if (walk) {
                timer.start();
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }

        public boolean isWaving() {
            return timer.isRunning();
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.white);

            int height = getHeight();

            if (options % 2 == 0) {
                g2.drawOval(50, 100, 50, 50);
                g2.drawOval(60, 110, 8, 8);
                g2.fillOval(60, 110, 8, 8);
                g2.drawOval(80, 110, 8, 8);
                g2.fillOval(80, 110, 8, 8);
                g2.drawArc(65, 130, 100, 0, 140, 30);
                g2.drawLine(75, 150, 75, 220);
                g2.drawLine(75, 180, 100, 160);
                g2.drawLine(75, 180, 65, 210);
                g2.drawLine(75, 220, 50, 260);
                g2.drawLine(75, 220, 100, 260);
            } else {
                g2.drawOval(50, 100, 50, 50);
                g2.drawOval(60, 110, 8, 8);
                g2.fillOval(60, 110, 8, 8);
                g2.drawOval(80, 110, 8, 8);
                g2.fillOval(80, 110, 8, 8);
                g2.drawArc(65, 130, 100, 0, 140, 30);
                g2.drawLine(75, 150, 75, 220);
                g2.drawLine(75, 180, 100, 180);
                g2.drawLine(75, 180, 65, 210);
                g2.drawLine(75, 220, 50, 260);
                g2.drawLine(75, 220, 100, 260);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You shouldn't be using `JFrame.HEIGHT` this actually has nothing to do with the frames height, but is part of the `ImageObserver` support... or any type of magic number for that matter

Comment: You are awesome! I was having trouble overriding the paintComponent method, and I realized it has to be protected, idk what that means but thank you for going the extra mile and helping me!

Comment: A `protected` method means that only the class the declared it, class in the same package and any child classes that extend it can call the method.  Check out [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details

Comment: usage reserved Java methods names `static class **paintComponent** extends JComponent{`